# Left/right adjoints to core/Cartesian inclusions

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, fibered-categories

Let $p:E\to B$ be a fibration and let $Cart(E)$ denote the subcategory of $E$ with all objects but only Cartesian arrows. Since all isomorphisms in $E$ are Cartesian, we naturally have  inclusion functors $$Core(E)\hookrightarrow Cart(E)\hookrightarrow E$$ Under what conditions do these inclusions have left/right adjoints? Is the existence of left/right adjoints to these inclusions equivalent to some known condition on $E$?

---

Dylan Wilson correctly points out that the inclusion out of $Core(E)$ has a left or right adjoint iff it's an equivalence since the relevant counit/unit would be an isomorphism. I'm still curious if the inclusion $Cart(E)\hookrightarrow E$ having a left or right adjoint is equivalent to any interesting known conditions.

Comment: The inclusion Core(E)-->E has an adjoint if and only if it is an equivalence (since the relevant unit/counit would be an isomorphism making the inclusion fully faithful).

Comment: @DylanWilson Good point, thanks; I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: In the case where the base is the terminal category, a morphism in the total category is cartesian if and only if it is an isomorphism. So I expect the answer to your question is either uninteresting or depends on the base category.

Comment: If the adjoint ends up commuting with the projection to the base, then this argument shows that the map Cart(E)-->E had to be an equivalence (so that E is a right fibration).